# If $x \in (\varphi(0) +\langle \varphi'(0)\rangle^\bot)\cap B_\delta(\varphi(0))$, do we have $|x-\varphi(0)|\le C\cdot |x-\varphi|$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curves

Consider a 1-periodic function $\varphi \in C^1(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^n)$ with non-vanishing derivative and such that $\varphi|_{[0,1)}$ is a bijection. Let

$$ N:=\{\varphi(0)+z\,|\,z\in\mathbb R^n, \, z^\top\varphi'(0)=0\}= \varphi(0) +\langle \varphi'(0)\rangle^\bot \subset \mathbb R^n$$

the hyperplane that is orthogonal to the closed curve $\varphi(\mathbb R)=\varphi([0,1])$ in the point $\varphi(0)$.

***Question:*** Is there a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in N \cap B_\delta(\varphi(0))$ we have
$$|x-\varphi(0)|\le C\cdot |x-\varphi|,$$
where the constant $C>0$ is independent of $x$ and where $|x-\varphi| :=\inf_{t\in[0,1]}|x-\varphi(t)|$ is the distance between $x$ and the curve?

It is clear that as $x$ approaches the curve, $|x-\varphi(0)|$ will converge to $|x-\varphi|$, but can we even establish such a local bound? If $\varphi'$ is constant in a neighborhood of 0, we even have $|x-\varphi(0)|= |x-\varphi|$. So if $\varphi'$ is continuous, the above shouldn't be too far-fetched, or am I missing something?

I suppose that people from differential geometry (which I am hardly familiar with at all) might know more about this kind of problem than me...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It seems that the answer to your question is positive under slightly stronger assumptions. Firstly, you have to require $\varphi$ to be one-to-one as a map $\varphi:S^1\to\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)\Leftrightarrow x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$. Secondly, you need the derivative $\varphi'$ to be non-vanishing (otherwise the image of $\varphi$ may be highly non-regular). Finally, you *may* have to assume $\varphi$ is at least $C^2$. If it is, then it has a *tubular neighborhood* and the answer to your question is positive with $C=1$. I'm not sure about the $C^1$ case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful comment! Your remarks about bijectivity and the non-vanishing derivative are of course right and I edited my question accordingly. This is the first time I hear the term *tubular neighborhood* - I'll look into that.

Comment: Can you give me a reference where I can find the statement for $C^2$-curves?

Comment: You could start by reading the Wiki page about tubular neighborhoods. This should give you an intuitive understanding of the matter. Then, you could try the references at the bottom of the page. Background in differential geometry may be needed.

Comment: It seems like [these](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~schnuere/skripte/difftopo.pdf) (German) lecture notes say in Theorem 1.16 that this is even true for $C^1$-curves. Am I misreading them? I hope the statement in the pdf is sufficiently understandable without knowing German...

Comment: I actually know *some* German. This was the first time I read math in German, and it was quite enjoyable. I believe there is a slight inaccuracy in the notes. Specifically, in the proof of Theorem 1.16, it says that "the tangent bundle $NM$ is locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ (please correct me if I got the German wrong). Now, this statement is only true if $M$ is at least $C^2$, as $NM$ is defined by means of the tangent bundle to $M$. In other words, as we move along $M$, the tangent spaces change *continuously* (and not more than that), and so do the orthogonal

Comment: complements. Hence, $NM$ is only locally *homeomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$, and we cannot use the inverse function theorem.

Comment: I think the $C^1$ curve $\gamma(t)=\left(t,|t|^{3/2}\right)$ is a counterexample to Corollary 1.17 in the notes. (It is not a counterexample to the claim in your question, though).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and thanks for sharing your enlightening thoughts. I think I now have some feeling for the statement itself and for the role of second derivatives.